# Correct order to write IF conditionals?

Tags: javascript, php

I realize this is a really simple and basic question.  I understand that in most programming languages, certainly all of them that I'm familiar with anyway, you can put your conditionals in any order.  However, I'm wondering what the rational would be to put them "backwards".

To explain, here are two examples:

```
if (x === 10) {}
if (10 === x) {}
```

I've always done it the first way, and pretty much everything I've always seen does it the first way.  However, every so often, I see it written the second way.  Other than that perhaps the coder in question is dyslexic or something, I'm wondering if there is any particular reason for the second (as I call it, the "backwards") order?

The main reason I'm asking is, I've never seen code by anyone that uses the second style that's poorly done.  It's always excellent code, which makes me wonder if there's something to it that I'm simply not aware of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yoda conditions are just fine, and it generally makes no difference

Comment: There is literally no difference, so just do whichever you like. Personally I (and I think many others) would prefer the first because in spoken language "if x is equal to 10" is much more natural-sounding than "if 10 is equal to x" even though they mean the same thing...

Comment: Only reason I could think of is that you could get errors if you mess up. Doing `$x = 10` would always be true, but `10 = $x` wouldn't because you can't assign to a number. So if you make an error (missing some =), it'd get noticed.

Comment: They're the same. Imagine if they were both variables. `x===y` or `y===x`. It makes no difference.

Comment: @Qirel That's a good point. It guards against that particular typo...

Comment: @Qirel - assignment inside conditions are generally bad practice anyway.

Comment: Exactly, because the interpreter wouldn't throw errors for doing `$x = 10`. It's a logical issue, not a syntactical one.

Comment: @adeneo My point is to demonstrate that if you type, by mistake, `$x = 10`, the other way would throw errors (if you ment to do comparison anyway, I'm not saying that you should assign it like that).

Comment: Still, it's "primarily opinion-based" ...

Comment: @adeneo: Yoda conditionals...  that's an awesome way to refer to them... I'm stealing that one.

Comment: Very much so. And assignments in conditions may be valid, consider fetching from a database, doing `if ($row = $stmt->fetch())`, you could of course assign outside, and check on `$row` after, but they're pretty much one and the same.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: @Qirel's That actually makes a lot of sense, you should make that an Answer so I can give you credit for that one :)  I don't see myself doing that, my brain works If This then That rather than That then This... but.. its a solid reason for why someone would do it that way.

Comment: @Qirel - that's sort of a good point, but caching typos is not a good reason to write unreadable code with yoda conditions.

Comment: I never defended writing it that way, I personally don't like it it all, but its the only logical reason I can understand *someone does* ;-) @adeneo

Comment: Well, I think it's okay in PHP, even Wordpress seems to suggest it -> https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions However in Javascript it's generally not a good idea to write Yoda conditions, but in some cases it might make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Yoda syntax or a Yoda Conditional. It is a matter of style mostly; however, its proponents use it as a way of avoiding assignment operations inside conditional statements. For instance: within an if statement, if one were to accidentally use a single equal sign instead of two, this would likely be a mistake and one which may be easily overlooked when debugging.

```
if( x = 7 )...
```

In this case x is assigned the value 7.

```
if( 7 = x )...
```

In this case it is a compilation error.

Here're more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: How can you say that? Did you deploy your code without testing?

Comment: @harishsharma it's just an example of why someone may wish to use Yoda syntax. I am not a fan myself, but I do understand why someone may wish to use it.

Comment: Confusing to my mind this is.  Able to write code in this way, I am not.  Still, thank you all - I didn't know there was an actual term for it.  SO rocks :)